# Device ID for floppy disk controller and floppy disk drives

Tags: windows-10, drivers, floppy

I noticed that some of the older computer (bought years ago) has a floppy disk controller and floppy disk drive device ID detected. The respective device ID detected were:

Floppy disk drive: ACPI\PNP0700\XXXXX

Floppy disk controller: FDC\GENERIC_FLOPPY_DRIVE\XXXXX

My first question would be: Are the above 2 device IDs referring to an actual physical floppy disk drive and floppy disk controller chip?

Secondly, I would like to ask if internal floppy disk drives require any software drivers to work as I am unsure if the device ID above are referring to a physical peripheral or a software driver (i.e. Bluetooth drivers do have device IDs too).

PS: I have tried googling but the most I could find is that Win10 PC could download floppy drivers to use internal floppy drives, but it did not answer what is the device ID it would generate (i.e. Is the format similar to how an actual internal floppy drive is or does it adopt a different naming convention?)

Do take note that the internal floppy drive I am referring to is an actual physical floppy drive and not a USB floppy drive.

Comment: You are asking for archaic technology. It should work, theoretically.

Comment: The floppy controller and drive are typically not self-identifying devices, and therefore have to be manually configured in order to be identified and used.  All peripheral devices have a (software) device driver; that is how the OS is organized.  You may not have to manually install a driver for a device, but that does not mean that there is no driver (e.g. the driver could be already built-in).

Comment: @sawdust Based on your explanation, do you mean that the device IDs identified above are referring to the software drivers?

Comment: *"...do you mean that the device IDs identified above are referring to the software drivers?"* -- No. *"Device IDs"* would refer to hardware devices.  Drivers are typically referred to by a name.  *"My first question would be ..."* -- You probably have the drive and controller designations swapped.

Comment: You should have posted this question over here>>>>>https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/